# Bar code is not populating properly in IText

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using ItextSharp, with that I'm population the form fields, in that some field is bar code, i declared as text filed in template level, and I'm replacing with Image.

**Code:**

```
private void addBarcode(PdfStamper stamper, AcroFields fields, String barcodeValue, String fieldName) throws Exception
{
 try
 {
    PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(1);
    Barcode barcode = new Barcode39();
    barcode.setCode(barcodeValue);
    barcode.setFont(null);
    barcode.setBarHeight(10f);
    Image image39 = barcode.createImageWithBarcode(overContent, BaseColor.BLACK, null);
    List<FieldPosition> barcodeArea = fields.getFieldPositions(fieldName);
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(barcodeArea))
    {
        return;
    }
    Rectangle rect = barcodeArea.get(0).position;
    image39.scaleToFit(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    image39.setAbsolutePosition(rect.getLeft() + (rect.getWidth() - image39.getScaledWidth()) / 2, rect.getBottom() + (rect.getHeight() - image39.getScaledHeight()) / 2);
    overContent.addImage(image39);
  } catch (Exception ex)
  {
   LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
   throw ex;
  }
 }
```

Same code working differently(same code i called in three places). images are attached below.Third one is fine other two are not ok, gray color barcode is coming.
**Image1:**

[image: Gray color bar code]
**Image2:**

[image: Gray color bar code]
**Image3:**

[image: exact one]

i tried `stamper.getUnderContent(1);` also.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you replace `getUnderContent` with `getOverContent`? Is the barcode still gray?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie that barcode itself disappeared.

Comment: I see that you solved the problem. There is something wrong with the *graphics state* in your PDF. The bar code isn't gray, but covered with a shape that is transparent. My solution would have been to fix the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setted Opacity.This issue is resolved.

**Code:**

```
PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
state.setFillOpacity(100f);
overContent.setGState(state);
```